# filling framebuffer with square

Tags: c, arrays, framebuffer

I am attempting to fill an unsigned character array with an ASCII art square, then print it on the screen. Currently this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define W 80
#define H 23

static int clear(unsigned char *p, int lim)
{
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < lim; i++)
                p[i] = ' ';
        return i;
}

static int square(unsigned char *p, int x, int y, int wh)
{
        int i, j;

        for (i = y; i < wh; i++) {
                for (j = x; j < wh; j++)
                        p[j] = '@';
                p[i] = '\n';
        }

        return i - j;
}

int main(void)
{
        unsigned char buf[W * H];
        clear(buf, sizeof buf);
        square(buf, 1, 2, 3);
        fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof buf, stdout);

        return 0;
}
```

This code, when compiled will result in nothing being printed, not being printed properly etc..

Here's the result from the code I want:

```
  @@@
  @@@
  @@@
```

Any help is appreciated, since I do not understand how filling a framebuffer and then printing it to the screen works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
static void point(unsigned char *p, int x, int y, unsigned char ch){
    if(x < W && y < H)
        p[W*y + x] = ch;
}

static void square(unsigned char *p, int x, int y, int wh){
    int i, j;

    for (i = y; i < y + wh; i++) {
        for (j = x; j < x + wh; j++)
            point(p, j, i, '@');
    }
}
```

Comment: The newline is required when the size of the console and the buffer is different. Use a different function rather than using the fwrite such a case.